# Is possible to use React Native *only for UI* and the logic in .NET?

Tags: f#, react-native, cross-platform

I need to create a multi-platform app for web, ios, android and partially desktop.

I wish to use .NET/F#, but the UI is a complication. I have tried Xamarin.Forms and it is too limited to me. I could live to use React Native but I don't wanna to code the full app in javascript, instead, I wish to use F# for all the logic and web backend, and use react only for the UI in mobile.

But I wonder how?

How feed data to the UI and react to events there?

P.D: If nativescript make this possible I'm all ears. I'm still not rule out xamarin for it, but forms is too limited and the nature of the apps and so far think react native is the closer to my needs.

Comment: I only know that it exists, but maybe have a look at Fable with React Native. http://www.navision-blog.de/blog/2016/08/06/fable-react-native/

Comment: The F# code is compiled to JS. Instead, I wanna to drive the UI from F#, not to use F# as replacement for JS.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a sample of this, because the entry file of the Fable React Native demo is a [pure JS file that calls the JS generated by Fable](https://github.com/fsprojects/fable-react_native-demo/blob/master/index.android.js#L3). You just need to extend this pure JS layer and import the code generated by Fable when needed.

Comment: But If I wanna use not JS libraries for the logic but F#? For example, do http request with F# libraries, not use F# to convert call to JS libraries.